# Idiom/phrase for rolling rotation

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

I am looking for idiom or a phrase I can use to describe rotational support process. The process explained as follows:

- Week 1: team member A and team member B are in charge of supporting group 1. Team member C and team member D are in charge of supporting group 2
- Week 2: team member D and team member A are in charge of supporting group 1. Team member B and team member C are in charge of supporting group 2
- Week 3: team member C and team member D are in charge of supporting group 1. Team member A and team member B are in charge of supporting group 2
- continue

This reminds me of *rolling forcasts* in finance and *rolling-window* in Computer. However, I am looking for an idiom/phrase which I can use for day-to-day work (not field specific). Is there any?

Comment: Rotational assignments?

Comment: There isn't a dedicated Business (Studies) SE, but surely this request is for jargon outside the domain of standard English usage?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth jargon would be sufficient

Answer (score 2):

The common term for this in business is **Job Rotation**.

> Job rotation is a technique used by some employers to rotate their
> employees' assigned jobs throughout their employment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_rotation

Both **Staff Rotation** and **Team Rotation** are widely understood variations on this which would fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Job Rotation does not describe the part of not the entire team is rotating. In my case, I have three teams. Only one person from each team slides to the next job at every rotation, and not the entire team.

Comment: I think something like "members of the team will provide support in rotation" or "in a rotating fashion" is probably as good as you'll get.